# Is there anyway to use GNOME terminal on macOS?

Tags: macos, unix, open-source

Can I download GNOME terminal on macOS?

Answer (score 8):

If you [install MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php), you can install the GNOME Terminal from the macOS Terminal.app:

`sudo port install gnome-terminal`

You can also install many other GNOME apps.

```
$ port search gnome
[...]
gnome-calculator @3.26.0_1 (gnome)
    Calculator with financial and scientific modes.

gnome-calendar @3.24.3_3 (gnome)
    Calendar is a calendar application for GNOME.
[...]
gnome-terminal @3.26.2 (gnome)
    Terminal component for the GNOME 3 Desktop

[...]
Found 158 ports.
```

[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) has a collection of over 20,000 open-source software for Mac. You can see all of the [available ports here](https://ports.macports.org).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to run GNOME terminal app in macOS or change the built in Terminal.app to GNOME terminal.

There are third party terminal emulator apps such as [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) available for macOS as well with other features.

Both macOS Terminal.app and iTerm2.app supports multiple tabs in a single app window, thus enabling the user to run multiple sessions concurrently.