# Devanagari font in macOS Terminal not rendering properly

Tags: macos, terminal, font, internationalization, input-source

**[Setup] -**

- I have a M1 Mac mini running Big Sur.
- I am using Devanagari-QWERTY input method for typing Marathi/Hindi.

**[Problem] -**

- All is well when typing in apps like Pages, Stickies, Safari etc..
- But when I type in Terminal app, the rendering is not as expected.

See below images.
What could be the issue and how to fix this?

[image: Devanagari-QWERTY input method]

[image: Rendering ok in Stickies app]

[image: Rendering not ok in Terminal app]

Comment: Try switching to a different terminal profile.

Comment: I tried a few other profiles (in preferences) and also various font settings (under profile), but I am unable to get anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Apple's Terminal has never supported correct Devanagari display, but have read that Gnome Terminal does.  You could try that.

[Is there anyway to use GNOME terminal on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336767/is-there-anyway-to-use-gnome-terminal-on-macos)

For vim also try searching/asking in [its stackexchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com).

If you find something that works, by all means come back here and let us know.

Comment: I see. I’ll try this out. I basically want to run vim inside terminal to type Devanagari. Hope I’ll be able to do that using your solution.

Comment: by the way, is this an issue with the terminal or with zsh shell? I also tried using another terminal "Alacritty" but the result is the same. Do you know any other terminals which support Devanagari, apart from gnome? (For gnome terminal, I need macports and also entire xcode which takes up too much space for my need.)

Comment: No idea about shells.  Try some different ones yourself to test that. My research only came up with gnome as a possibility.  Get a cheap external ssd if you need more space.