# How to run gnome-terminal (MacPorts) gtk-doc error

Tags: terminal, unix, macports

I have installed gnome-terminal via Mac Ports following this post:
[Is there anyway to use GNOME terminal on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336767/is-there-anyway-to-use-gnome-terminal-on-macos)

However, I can't seem to find information on how to run the the terminal? Any ideas.

I've already done

```
sudo port install gnome-terminal
```

Okay this actually did not get installed because of an error missing gtk-doc
Here's my ticket hopefully it is helpful.
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/62941

Comment: Why gnome-terminal?  What's deficient in iTerm2?

Comment: I have a bash script I wrote (im a linux user) for a new job... however they also gave me a Mac computer. The script opens 2 windows with 3 terminals in each and automatically sets up a dev environment. It's a pretty simple script but dont know how to port it to mac so just figured ill just port the terminal.

Comment: @Gilby https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420906/how-to-open-mac-terminals-with-bash-script-convert-this-linux-script

Comment: Hopefully you get a good answer from the other thread using either Terminal or iTerm2.

Comment: What do you mean with not knowing how to run it? Doesn‘t a binary get installed you can just start?

Comment: I already installed it with mac ports but I don't know how to go about running it... typing gnome-terminal into the mac terminal doesn't work.

Comment: You sure you didn't get `Error: Processing of port gnome-terminal failed` when trying to install `gnome-terminal`?  I ask because I've tried to install it twice now and get that error.  BTW What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 man multi tasking and these 70 hour weeks got me mis reading... you are absolutely right. I am debugging it right now and filing a bug request with Mac ports. My dconf won't install because it can't access gtkdocsize... I downloaded brew and installed gtkdoc and gtk+3 but no luck. I am on Big Sur 11.3.1