# How to open Mac terminals with Bash script (convert this Linux script)

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh

I am a Linux user but just got a new job and was looking to convert this script which sets up a dev environment with 6 terminals (2 windows of 3 tabs each) to Mac to help my new mac user co-workers.

```sh
# work-dbs (rabbit-dev, database-dev, redis-dev)
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'sh -c "ssh -N rabbit-dev -v; exec bash"' --tab -e 'sh -c "ssh -N database-dev -v; exec bash"' --tab -e 'sh -c "ssh -N redis-dev -v; exec bash"'

# work-apis (work1, work2, work3)
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'sh -c "cd work1-api; yarn run start:development; exec bash"' --tab -e 'sh -c "cd work2-api; yarn run start:development; exec bash"' --tab -e 'sh -c "cd work3-api; yarn run start:development; exec bash"'
```

Comment: I'd look into using **iTerm2**, over **Terminal**, as it is much better at being scripted. **iTerm2** can use **AppleScript** and or **Python** for its scripting, although **AppleScript** is depreciated in **iTerm2** it still current works.

Comment: If I switched to Iterm2 would it be easy to convert this above script from gnome-terminal to iterm2?

Comment: RE: "If I switched to Iterm2 would it be easy to convert this above script from gnome-terminal to iterm2?" -- "easy" is subjective along with one's ability to _code_ in **AppleScript** and or **Python**. IMO It would be so much easier in **iTerm2**, as **Terminal** is not well suited for scripting compared to **iTerm2**. I'd suggest you start by going to https://iterm2.com and see what it has to offer.

Comment: Interesting Ill check it out... my initial go to was macports with gnome-terminal... ive downloaded and installed but curious how to run it still. Limited time right now. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420877/how-to-run-gnome-terminal-macports?noredirect=1&lq=1